# How can i check this function is called from which file?

Tags: c

see i have one library which has two api lets call

```
api1()
```

and

```
 api2()
```

Now internally api2 calls api1 also.

so in one situation i want to do is that

- when some other application is calling api1() then do some special work
- but when api2() calls api1() then do'nt do that special work.

how can i do that ?

Is there any way so i can know that api1() is calling from library itself not application?

**Edit :**

```
api1()
{
sem_wait();  // this create deadlock 

// do some task 

sem_post();
}
```

now api2() is like this

```
  api2()
{
sem_wait();

api1();

sem_post();

}
```

see my both function...when application calls api1() i need to be work in sem_wait and sem_post but when api2() calls api1() then i dont want to sem_wait again because its make dead locks ...

**i need some mechanism so api1() checks if it  is being called from api2() then dont use sem_wait and sem_post**

Comment: Why would you let a function do two different things, depending on who calls it?

Comment: The edits changed the question's context rather much; my earlier answer which was IMO reasonable to the original question is dangerous in light of these edits, and I have therefore deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often done something like this:

```
// internal function
static int api1_internal(void) {
  do stuff assuming the lock is held;
}

// function for external callers, doing extra locking
int api1(void) {
  int ret;
  lock();
  ret = api1_internal();
  unlock();
  return ret;
}

// some internal function using internal api1
void internalfunc(void) {
  lock();
  do some things();
  api1_internal();
  unlock();
}
```

Note api1_internal is declared static to stop anything outside that file using it.

If you really want to confuse yourself you could put the definition of api1() first, then have something like

```
#define api1 api1_internal
```

Which would keep your code pretty, but just confuse you later. Don't do that.

It's common to use a leading underscore for internal, non-locking versions of functions, so

```
static int _api1(void)
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not easy to achieve by introspection. You could investigate the call stack but that is very non-portable and really not to be recommended.

One way to deal with this is to pass a parameter to control the variation of behaviour. This has the addition benefit of making the function's behaviour more transparent and explicit. As @blueshift points out, this can place a burden on external callers. Splitting the function into two versions, one for internal use and one for external use relieves that burden.

---

In light of your edit, I think the design is a little off. The synchronization responsibility should either be internal to the function, or external. It's very risky to make that responsibility sometimes be internal and sometimes be external. That would be one way round the problem. Another way around it would be to use recursive locks.

Comment: Not nice if it means all external callers have to pass an extra parameter which is always "external". And breaks if they ever set it differently.

Comment: @blueshift Yes, your approach would work well. I didn't think out of the box to having two different functions as a way around this.

Comment: I just stole the approach of various things in the Linux kernel :) Standing on the shoulders of giants.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need two different function calls (function name or parameter) for the two different jobs (+special work and -special work). Context-sensitive functions are not only not supported by C, but absolutely and totally evil because they add a whole Chomsky of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your library so that `api2()` tells `api1()` that it is the caller. When called from outside, `api1()` sees an unknown caller.